# Property 'distinctUntilChanged()' does not exist on type MonoTypeOperatorFunction<{}> Rxjs6

Tags: typescript, angular6, rxjs6

I am trying to create a search service for real time searching in input. I have 
**`search.service.ts`** :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SearchService {

  baseUrl: string = 'https://api.cdnjs.com/libraries';
  queryUrl: string = '?search=';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  search(terms: Observable<string>) {
    return terms.pipe(debounceTime(400)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .switchMap(term => this.searchEntries(term)));
  }

  searchEntries(term) {
    this.http.get(this.baseUrl + this.queryUrl + term).pipe(map(res => {
      res.json();
    }))
  }
}
```

and 
**`app.component.ts`**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SearchService } from './search.service';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [SearchService]
})
export class AppComponent {
  results: Object;
  searchTerm$ = new Subject<string>();

  constructor(private searchService: SearchService) {
    this.searchService.search(this.searchTerm$)
      .subscribe(results => {
        this.results = results.results;
      });
  }
}
```

I am facing a problem in `search.service.ts` **Property 'distinctUntilChanged()' does not exist on type MonoTypeOperatorFunction<{}>**. How can I fix this? Please give suggestions.

**EDITED**
The code below fixed the issue.

```
search(terms: Observable<string>) {
        return terms.pipe(debounceTime(400),
            distinctUntilChanged(),
            switchMap(() => interval(50), term => this.searchEntries(term)));
    }
```

You can visit my code for this project [on github](https://github.com/NodiraIbrogimova/real-time-search-ng6)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your call to `pipe` is incorrect.  The operators in pipe should be separate, not chained by `.`:

```
return terms.pipe(debounceTime(400),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  switchMap(term => this.searchEntries(term)));
```

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. This solved the issue with distinctUntilChanged(), but another error with switchMap occured. The final view of function is:   `search(terms: Observable<string>) {
    return terms.pipe(debounceTime(400),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap(_ => interval(50), term => { this.searchEntries(term) }));
  }`

Comment: @ Mikhail Burshteyn, I will also update the question with answer below. Thank you for feedback. Have a productive day!